# Error when rbindlist in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I get this error when trying to get a `data.table`. Is there a way to solve it?

```
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Expected sep (',') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends 
  field 0 when detecting types from point 10: 

files=list.files(pattern="*csv")
prices = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: It works when doing prices = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, sep="\t"), fill=TRUE), but now I have 1 column because the right sep is "," not "/t"

Comment: maybe `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, fill = TRUE), fill = TRUE)`?

Comment: @Jaap it works! thanks